# How should I understand the "Bunch class" in python?

Tags: python

Today I have learnt a Bunch class from the book < Python algorithm >

```
class Bunch(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(Bunch, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self.__dict__ = self
```

But I'm not quite understanding what does the third line do:

```
super(Bunch, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
```

I know it will call the parent class, and do something like:

```
dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
```

But I have no idea what does the  __init__ function do to the dict.

How should I understand that?

Comment: The `__init__` method is usually used to initialize attributes.

Comment: You can do `dict(a=2, b=3)`, `dict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of `dict.__init__` as the dictionary constructor.  e.g. I can write:

```
d = dict(a=1, b=2)
```

or

```
d = dict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])
```

Both create (initialize) the dictionary `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`.  Whenever I write those two statements, it calls `dict.__init__` which is what does the job of adding the `a` and `b` items.

In the same way, with `Bunch`, it causes all of the keyword arguments (or an iterable of 2-sequences) to be turned into key-value pairs in the dictionary subclass (`Bunch`).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know exactly what `dict__init__` does.  The way to think about it is that `dict.__init__` does what is necessary to make the object "work like a dict".  In general, when you subclass, you need to call the superclass `__init__` to make the class "work like" its superclass, and the same is true when subclassing a builtin type like dict.